# How to reset a problem in a category on my e-commerce site?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

as you can see on my website [www.bmhotellerie.it](http://www.bmhotellerie.it) in the Take away category the products are displayed badly, I would like some advice on how to restore

Comment: You can see the problem here on this link
https://www.bmhotellerie.it/categoria-prodotto/take-away-e-monouso/

Comment: The problem is somewhere in your open / closed tags of your content-product or filters that modify the template. You can see the issue at many places Shop, Single product (related products), Product category etc. I will advise you if you work on the templates to use child theme. If its theme issue by itself (you havent modify) contact your theme developer. He will be able to point where the issue is and provide fix while new update comes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think it is category related. Here is the same issue on the same product, on the shop page :

https://www.bmhotellerie.it/shop/page/3/

It seems you have an unclosed tag somewhere on your product template.

[image]

As you can see, your `.item-col` element is inside another `.item-col` element.

Usually, it's the template `templates/content-product.php` that display products within loops :

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.6.0/templates/content-product.php

My first guess will be to look at this template if your theme contains it. If not, maybe there is a hook or another template that create this issue...?

Comment: Hi how can I watch this theme ?? can you explain to me step by step?